# Is it possible to include existing excel functions in a custom ribbon?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, ribbonx, excel-web-addins

Within an **Office Excel JavaScript Add in**, I created a **custom ribbon.**
Within that **custom ribbon**, I would like to **include custom excel functions** (e.g., remove duplicates).

Is it possible, to include such functions? If yes, what does an exemplary XAML code for the manifest file look like? Where can I find the relevant **IDs for Excel**?

I did not find any resources on possible code snippets. Further, I did not find any related articles for Excel JS Add-Ins specifically in the documentation?

Comment: If you are asking about Excel [custom functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-overview), they cannot be run from a ribbon button. If that is not what you are talking about, please clarify. (BTW, the XML in the manifest is not XAML.)

Comment: Hey Rick, thank you for your answer! I am not asking about excel custom functions, but rather about including existing excel commands that are accessible in other parts of the XLS Ribbon. I would like to add those to my custom ribbon. Is that possible? If yes, how would I need to adjust the manifest file? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I suspect the user wants to include existing, built-in, Excel ribbon controls on the ribbon tab of the add-in?

Comment: @user21249614 That is possible in PowerPoint, (see https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/design/built-in-button-integration), but not in Excel.

Comment: Thank you @jkpieterse, that is correct :). Great, I understand that this is not possible in excel. Thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

Ribbon controls can't invoke Excel custom functions directly. If you need to deliver custom functions with custom ribbon UI you need to [Configure your Office Add-in to use a shared runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime). It lists all the required modifications you need to make in the manifest file.

You may find the [Tutorial: Share data and events between Excel custom functions and the task pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/share-data-and-events-between-custom-functions-and-the-task-pane-tutorial).